# Does a WPF .NET 3.0 Date Picker exist?

Tags: .net, wpf, datepicker

I am trying to find a WPF 3.0 date picker control. What can you recommend and where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book Applications = Code + Markup (Charles Petzold) in Chapter 25 has a datePicker control that the Microsoft team has converted to VB.net.  The control is written for .Net 3.0.  Here is a link to the control and source code.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=petzoldsamplevb&DownloadId=244

Answer (score 12):

The [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=25047) contains a DatePicker control.

**Edit:** I forgot to add a link to the [DatePicker Walkthrough](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-calendar-datepicker-walkthrough.aspx) for info how to use it.

**Update:** There is no DatePicker control from Microsoft that runs on .Net 3.0. You can either buy a third party DatePicker control, like [Telerik's DatePicker](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/datepicker.aspx) for example, or you can go with start with an [open source DatePicker](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/04/04/avaloncontrolslibrary-datepicker-refactored/) implementation and roll your own. Disclaimer: I have not used either of the third party DatePicker controls, so I can't vouch about their quality.

Comment: Make sure to use the January 2009 release of the WPF Toolkit. Previous versions had a memory leak in the date picker

Comment: Can't use it.  Our users are stuck on .Net 3.0.

Comment: You can download the WPF Toolkit source, change the target framework to 3.0, and then recompile.

Answer (score 3):

There's a free date picker control in Kevin's WPF bag-o-tricks at http://j832.com/bagotricks/

And in MS WPF toolkit has Franci Penov said.

I've used the bag-o-tricks one in the past, it works but it isn't perfect.