# How To Use DateTimePicker In WPF?

Tags: wpf, datetimepicker

I have no idea how to use the DateTimePicker control in WPF. It is not available in the Toolbox.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Please Note:** The following answer only applied to WPF under the 3.5 Framework as NET 4.0 runtime has it's own [datetime control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.aspx).

By default WPF 3.5 does not come with a date time picker like winforms.

However a date picker has been added in the [WPF tool kit](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=22567) produced by Microsoft which can be [downloaded here](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=22567). I guess it will become part of the framework in a future release.

It is simple to add a reference to the WPFToolkit.dll, see it in the tool box and distribute with your application by following the instructions on the website.

Before this was available other people had created 3rd party pickers (which you may prefer) or alternatively used the less ideal solution of using the winforms control in a WPF application.

**Update:** This so question is very similar [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534845/does-anyone-have-a-wpf-net-3-0-date-picker) which also has a link to a [walk through for the datepicker](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-calendar-datepicker-walkthrough.aspx) along with other links.

Comment: Just a small precaution that the toolkit one is not yet ready for production: http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Wiki/View.aspx?title=VSM%20Memory%20Leak

Comment: Strike that--it was fixed in the January re-release.

Comment: You're refering to the date picker not the dateTime picker.  I don't think this in in the WPF Toolkit unfort.

Comment: This answer is `[Obsolete]` :)

Comment: @greg - I have updated the answer to clarify this is only for 3.5 framework

Comment: The DatePicker control from WPF doesn't support time component, but the DateTimePicker from WPF Toolkit Extended does support it (I've been using it).

Answer (score 5):

This just came in ;)

There is a new DatePicker class for WPF in the .NET 4.0 runtime:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.aspx

Also see the "Whats new in WPF" for more nice features:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588.aspx

Comment: The DatePicker control from WPF doesn't support time component, but the DateTimePicker from WPF Toolkit Extended does support it (I've been using it)

Answer (score 3):

There is no out of the box DateTime picker for WPF..

There are however a lot of third party DateTime pickers of course :)

http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar-wpf/WPFDateTimePicker.aspx

http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/09/11/wpf-datepicker/

http://www.codeplex.com/AvalonControlsLib

Just do a quick google to find more!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this DateTimePicker has been mentioned before:

[A WPF DateTimePicker That Works Like the One in Winforms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfDateTimePicker.aspx)

That one is in VB and has some bugs. I converted it to C# and made a [new version with bug fixes](https://gist.github.com/1150228).

[image: DateTimePicker]

Note: I used the Calendar control in [WPFToolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) so that I could use .NET 3.5 instead of .NET 4. If you are using .NET 4, just remove references to "wpftc" in the XAML.

Answer (score 2):

For the controls embedded in WPF Extended WPF Toolkit Release 1.4.0, please refer
http://elegantcode.com/2011/04/08/extended-wpf-toolkit-release-1-4-0/

For Calendar & DatePicker Walkthrough please refer,
http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-calendar-datepicker-walkthrough.aspx

And you can cutomize the look and feel by Microsoft Expression Studio `[Use Edit Template option]`
Sample shows here:

Add following namespaces to xaml page

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended"
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Controls_Core_Converters="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Core.Converters;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended" 
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Controls_Chromes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Chromes;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended"
```

Add followings to Page/Window resources

```
<!--DateTimePicker Customized Style-->
        <Style x:Key="DateTimePickerStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DateTimePicker}">
            <Setter Property="TimeWatermarkTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Foreground="Gray" Focusable="False"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="WatermarkTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Foreground="Gray" Focusable="False"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DateTimePicker}">
                        <Border>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <toolkit:DateTimeUpDown AllowSpin="{TemplateBinding AllowSpin}" 
                                                                  BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" 
                                                                  FormatString="{TemplateBinding FormatString}" 
                                                                  Format="{TemplateBinding Format}" 
                                                                  ShowButtonSpinner="{TemplateBinding ShowButtonSpinner}" 
                                                                  Value="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                                                  WatermarkTemplate="{TemplateBinding WatermarkTemplate}" 
                                                                  Watermark="{TemplateBinding Watermark}" 
                                                                  Foreground="#FFEFE3E3" 
                                                                  BorderBrush="#FFEBB31A">
                                        <toolkit:DateTimeUpDown.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF2F2828" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </toolkit:DateTimeUpDown.Background>
                                    </toolkit:DateTimeUpDown>

                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="_calendarToggleButton" 
                                                  Background="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                        <ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible>
                                            <Binding Path="IsOpen" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                                <Binding.Converter>
                                                    <Microsoft_Windows_Controls_Core_Converters:InverseBoolConverter/>
                                                </Binding.Converter>
                                            </Binding>
                                        </ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible>
                                        <ToggleButton.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                                                <Microsoft_Windows_Controls_Chromes:ButtonChrome x:Name="ToggleButtonChrome" CornerRadius="0,2.75,2.75,0" InnerCornerRadius="0,1.75,1.75,0" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                                                                    <Microsoft_Windows_Controls_Chromes:ButtonChrome.Background>
                                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="1"/>
                                                                            <GradientStop Color="#7FC0A112"/>
                                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                                    </Microsoft_Windows_Controls_Chromes:ButtonChrome.Background>
                                                                </Microsoft_Windows_Controls_Chromes:ButtonChrome>
                                                                <Grid>
                                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                                                    <Grid x:Name="arrowGlyph" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="5">
                                                                        <Path Data="M0,1C0,1 0,0 0,0 0,0 3,0 3,0 3,0 3,1 3,1 3,1 4,1 4,1 4,1 4,0 4,0 4,0 7,0 7,0 7,0 7,1 7,1 7,1 6,1 6,1 6,1 6,2 6,2 6,2 5,2 5,2 5,2 5,3 5,3 5,3 4,3 4,3 4,3 4,4 4,4 4,4 3,4 3,4 3,4 3,3 3,3 3,3 2,3 2,3 2,3 2,2 2,2 2,2 1,2 1,2 1,2 1,1 1,1 1,1 0,1 0,1z" Fill="#FF82E511" Height="4" Width="7"/>
                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                </Grid>
                                                            </Grid>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Style>
                                        </ToggleButton.Style>
                                    </ToggleButton>
                                </Grid>

                                <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=_calendarToggleButton}" StaysOpen="False">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1" Padding="3">
                                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFD2C217" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFE9B116" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <StackPanel Background="{x:Null}">
                                            <Calendar x:Name="Part_Calendar" BorderThickness="0" DisplayDate="2011-06-28" Background="#7FE0B41A"/>
                                            <toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="Part_TimeUpDown" Format="ShortTime" Value="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" WatermarkTemplate="{TemplateBinding TimeWatermarkTemplate}" Watermark="{TemplateBinding TimeWatermark}" Background="{x:Null}" Style="{DynamicResource TimePickerStyle1}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="TimePickerStyle1" 
               TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:TimePicker}">
            <Setter Property="WatermarkTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Foreground="Gray" Focusable="False"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:TimePicker}">
                        <Border>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <toolkit:DateTimeUpDown x:Name="PART_TimeUpDown" AllowSpin="{TemplateBinding AllowSpin}" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" FormatString="{TemplateBinding FormatString}" ShowButtonSpinner="{TemplateBinding ShowButtonSpinner}" Value="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" WatermarkTemplate="{TemplateBinding WatermarkTemplate}" Watermark="{TemplateBinding Watermark}" Background="#7FE0B41A" BorderBrush="#FFF9F2F2">
                                            <toolkit:DateTimeUpDown.Format>
                                                <TemplateBinding Property="Format">
                                                    <TemplateBinding.Converter>
                                                        <Microsoft_Windows_Controls_Core_Converters:TimeFormatToDateTimeFormatConverter/>
                                                    </TemplateBinding.Converter>
                                                </TemplateBinding>
                                            </toolkit:DateTimeUpDown.Format>
                                        </toolkit:DateTimeUpDown>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="_timePickerToggleButton" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
                                        <ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible>
                                            <Binding Path="IsOpen" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                                <Binding.Converter>
                                                    <Microsoft_Windows_Controls_Core_Converters:InverseBoolConverter/>
                                                </Binding.Converter>
                                            </Binding>
                                        </ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible>
                                        <ToggleButton.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                                            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                                                <Microsoft_Windows_Controls_Chromes:ButtonChrome x:Name="ToggleButtonChrome" CornerRadius="0,2.75,2.75,0" InnerCornerRadius="0,1.75,1.75,0" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"/>
                                                                <Grid>
                                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                                                    <Grid x:Name="arrowGlyph" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="5">
                                                                        <Path Data="M0,1C0,1 0,0 0,0 0,0 3,0 3,0 3,0 3,1 3,1 3,1 4,1 4,1 4,1 4,0 4,0 4,0 7,0 7,0 7,0 7,1 7,1 7,1 6,1 6,1 6,1 6,2 6,2 6,2 5,2 5,2 5,2 5,3 5,3 5,3 4,3 4,3 4,3 4,4 4,4 4,4 3,4 3,4 3,4 3,3 3,3 3,3 2,3 2,3 2,3 2,2 2,2 2,2 1,2 1,2 1,2 1,1 1,1 1,1 0,1 0,1z" Fill="Black" Height="4" Width="7"/>
                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                </Grid>
                                                            </Grid>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Style>
                                        </ToggleButton.Style>
                                    </ToggleButton>
                                </Grid>

                                <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=_timePickerToggleButton}" StaysOpen="False">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFE7C857" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.BorderBrush>

                                        <Grid>
                                            <ListBox x:Name="PART_TimeListItems" BorderThickness="0" DisplayMemberPath="Display" Height="130" Width="150" Background="#7FE0B41A">
                                                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                                    <Border x:Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                                                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Margin="4"/>
                                                                    </Border>
                                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#FFE7F5FD"/>
                                                                        </Trigger>
                                                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                                                        </Trigger>
                                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                                            </Setter.Value>
                                                        </Setter>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                            </ListBox>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

And in Window you can use the style as

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you want one without external libraries, I do have improved the one from Qwertie. It could be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69241500/9758687

[image: DateTimePicker]

Answer (score 1):

There is a `DateTimePicker` available in the [Extended Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker&referringTitle=Documentation).

Answer (score 0):

There is DatePicker in WPF Tool Kit, but I have not seen DateTime Picker in WPF ToolKit. So I don't know what kind of DateTimePicker control John is talking about.